# Is there a way to conditionally include attributes in custom JSP tag?

Tags: spring, jsp, custom-tags, conditional-attribute

Lets say I have a field that can take 3 attributes

```
<myTag a="something" b="something" c="something" />
```

Let's say I want to only include those a,b,c attributes when a variables are not blank. So with EL it becomes something like this

```
<myTag a="${varA}" b="${varB}" c="${varC}" />
```

In the case that one or more of the variables are blank (say varB is empty) I'm getting output like:

```
<myTag a="a val" b c="c val" />
```

So b is still there, but passing a blank value.
This can cause problems with some spring `<form:etc>` tags if an attribute is blank (say itemLabel on form:options for example) 
What if I don't want that? Is there an easy way to have the attribute not show up altogether?

I get that I can do

```
<c:if test="${empty b}">
    <myTag a="${varA}" c="${varC}" />
</c:if>
```

But that means we need a giant decision tree as the number of attributes increase if each one can possibly be blank.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: This is not a JSTL tag. This is a custom JSP tag. To learn what exactly JSTL is, head to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info I fixed the terminology in your question.